# Android game choppy on some devices but has high FPS

Tags: android

I am developing a game for android phones.  When I test my ggame on my galaxy s the frame rate is around 60 and the game is fairly smooth. But when I test the game on my brother's galaxy ace then the game is choppy even though the framerate is still 60.

I use libgdx and box2d for the game and rendering happens on the same thread as updating does.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you used method profiling on the Galaxy Ace?

Comment: No I have not, but Since the FPS is the same and there is no code running outside the render loop then I don't think it's be from a slow method. If you think otherwise please let me know

Comment: Considering that the GPU and CPU (A8 vs. A6) are slower yeah I think its a good idea.

Comment: Something that has happened to me before so I will ask, Does it seem choppy during garbage collection?  You can tell when garbage collection by watching logcat while the app is running and being choppy.  See http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/07/track-memory-allocations-on-android/ for some more ideas

Comment: I Think I figured it out, I think it was due to a bad implementation of my extrapolation system. Thanks for the help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a problem with position extrapolation - Thanks for the help